# Python Program to split a new file from a master file

Tags: python, list, split

I have a master file which has 4 columns.

```
Name Parent Child Property
A1 World USA 1
A2 USA Texas 2
A3 Texas Houston 3
A4 USA Austin 4
A5 World USA 5
A6 World Canada 6
A7 Canada Toronto 7
```

I need to create a new file and extract those records which are in between the keyword(USA) in column 3.

The output file should be :

```
Name Parent Child Property
A1 World USA 1
A2 USA Texas 2
A3 Texas Houston 3
A4 USA Austin 4
A5 World USA 5
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Please give an example of the expected output.

Comment: Do you mean first split on Child, then split on Parent? Can you show what is the expected output

Comment: Name Parent Child Property
A1 World USA 1
A2 USA Texas 2
A3 Texas Houston 3
A4 USA Austin 4
A5 World USA 5

Comment: This should be the output. Thanks for helping

Comment: What have you tried yourself, please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Please find the sample code and working fine on my test box

## !/usr/bin/python

import re

oldfile = open("old.txt", "r")  - -- > old.txt - source file with all contents
newfile = open("new.txt", "w")  - - -> new file to write the output

for line in oldfile:
    if re.match("(.*)USA(.*)", line):
       print >> newfile, line,

Output file:

cat new.txt
A1 World USA 1
A2 USA Texas 2
A4 USA Austin 4
A5 World USA 5